# When overflow hidden get only visible images

Tags: jquery

I have a html structure shown as image. Is there any way to get those images which are not full visible (last row) when the container is set as overflow hidden? I am able to get images which are hidden.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this custom selector to find elements not overflowing their parents:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
    inparent: function(el) {
        var $el = $(el),
        parent = $el.parent();
        if ($el.offset().top >= parent.offset().top && 
            $el.offset().top + $el.outerHeight(true) <= parent.offset().top + parent.outerHeight(true) && 
            $el.offset().left >= parent.offset().left && 
            $el.offset().left + $el.outerWidth(true) <= parent.offset().left + parent.outerWidth(true)) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

You can then find the images which are partially or fully hidden using:

```
var visibleimg = $('#container > img:not(:inparent)');
```

Comment: `var $el = $(el), parent = $el.parent();`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Changed, though I can't say it did more than shave off a few characters

Comment: 1. You had global `parent`. 2. Declaring $el you avoided creation of jQuery instance multiple times.
For better compression and performance I'd cache offsets as well. :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Too much work rewriting it now :P There are several things I could do to improve performance, e.g. an early exit structure that tries to exit after evaluating each condition instead of evaluating the whole `&&`

Comment: `&&` won't evaluate next condition if current was evaluated to `false`. That's why this line doesn't throw an error 
`var a = null, b = a&&a.something;`.

Comment: @Asad Thanks!! For ul li format I need to make some changes in script but your answer helped me a lot :)